# What is the best option to use redux actions when using redux hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I want to use redux hook useSelector to access the store and get rid of connect(), so I need to create a way to export my actions, and I'm thinking on a class with static methods, here is an example

```
export default class AuthActions {
    static async login(userData) {
        try {
            const user = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000', userData);

            dispatch({
                type: AUTH.LOGIN,
                payload: user.data
            })
        } catch (error) {
            dispatch({
                type: SET_ERROR,
                payload: error
            })
        }
    }

    static setUser() {
        console.log("SET USER")
    }

    static logout() {
        console.log("Logout")
    }
}
```

And then I use the action methods as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import AuthActions from '../../redux/actions/AuthActions';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';


export default const Login = () => {
  //More logic....
  const { isAuth } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);

  const submitHandler = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    AuthActions.login(userData)
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
      My Login form ....
    </form>
  );
};
```

But I'm wondering if there is a disadvantage or performance issues to use redux in this way, or should I avoid the usage of a class and use a simple object instead?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is something not working?  Don't worry about 'best option' or even try to optimize before hand.  https://stackify.com/premature-optimization-evil/

Answer (score 1):

this is my format of a reducer, inspired by [ducks-modular-redux](https://github.com/erikras/ducks-modular-redux)
for example, check out this darkMode reducer:

```
export const constants = {
  TOGGLE: "darkMode/TOGGLE"
};

export const actions = {
  toggleDarkMode: () => {
    return {
      type: constants.TOGGLE
    };
  }
};

export const thunks = {
  toggleDarkMode: () => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
      dispatch(actions.toggleDarkMode());
      const isDark = getState().darkMode.isDark;
      localStorage.setItem("isDark", isDark);
    };
  }
};

const initialState = { isDark: localStorage.getItem("isDark") === "true" };

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case constants.TOGGLE:
      return {
        isDark: !state.isDark
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: but if you distinguish `actions` and `thunks` you make consumer code knowing too much on implementation details. Say if your action becomes deferred or needs to send XHR you have to update consumer component as well. Keeping all in single list makes it easy to change that.